# Error: there is no registered task type 'npm'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm

I have installed nodejs(node-v14.17.6-x64) and i am using reactjs.But whenever I try to launch my application using google chrome from VS Code, I get this error

> Could not find the task 'npm:start'.

and I am able to launch the application using the url. why this issue is happening?

When hit on launch icon

[image]

error in terminal

[image]

Expectation:

I want to launch my application using the run button in vscode

[image]

Comment: show a launch.json for a [mre].